# Am I missing something in finding the mean and std. deviation for this lognormal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am told that I have a random variable $X$ and the mean of this random variable is $10,281$ and the coefficient of variation is $.4$. Since we know that coefficient of variation is $\frac{\sigma_x}{\mu_x}$ that would mean that the standard deviation of this random variable would be $4,116.4$ or something close, I don't have the number in front of me. I have a formula from class that says the expected value of a lognormal is equal to $\exp\left[\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right]$. But for whatever the reason the numbers aren't working out. I'm getting a number that's too big for my calculator to process. $\sigma^2$ is roughly 8 million and $e^{8,000,000}$ is quite large. So this can't be right. Am I missing something or is this another case of a bad textbook problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mean is equal to $10,281$ and the mean is equal to $\exp(\mu + \sigma^2/2)$.  So, set them equal to each other.  Similarly, for the variance.  That will give you two equations in two unknowns and then you can solve.  $\mu$ is not $10,281$.  $\exp(\mu + \sigma^2 /2)$ is $10,281$.  That's a huge difference.  $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are the mean and variance for a normal random variable.  They are parameters for a lognormal but not the mean and variance.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to give that a try. These darn lognormal distributions.